# No metadata error on Pythonista, how can I solve it?

Tags: python, pythonista

I am using Pythonista app for iPad Air. I am just a beginner. I just wanted to install modules from pypi with StaSh. I write on StaSh “pip install prettytable” then it is installed prettytable module with no promblem.

But when I tried to import prettytable and use print function for basic execution, it gives me an error about “no package metadata was found for prettytable”

I tried to execution another functions but didn’t change anything.